# Cannot render child components with React Router (Nested Routes)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am trying to use nested routes to render different components. When I click my links, URL does update but the components are not rendering. Prior to this I was using imported components, but since that wasn't working, I stripped it down to this block of code and it's still just showing a blank component and no errors.

```
        import React from 'react';

        import { Route, Switch, Link, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

        function InfluencerComponent() {
            let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

            const navLinks = (
                <div>
                    <Link to={`${url}/select-trade`}>Select trade</Link>
                    <Link to={`${url}/add-skills`} className="ml-2">
                        Add skills
                    </Link>
                </div>
            );
            return (
                <div className="row mt-3">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={path}>
                            {navLinks}
                        </Route>
                        <Route path={`${path}/select-trade`}>
                            {navLinks}
                            <Test />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path={`${path}/add-skills`}>
                            {navLinks}
                            <TestTwo />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            );
        }

        function Test() {
            return 'Test Component';
        }

        function TestTwo() {
            return 'Another Test Component';
        }

        export default InfluencerComponent;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Components are not rendering because you should use `component` prop instead of `children`.

*Example*:

```
    return (
        <div className="row mt-3">
            <Switch>
                // ...
                <Route path={`${path}/add-skills`} component={<>{navLinks}<TestTwo /></>} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
```

More info about `<Route />` props:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component

Comment: What happens if you remove `<Switch />` ?

Comment: Same result. I was going off of this example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting